# How can I put the navigation above the main layout container?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am new with R, and I am trying to get a custom layout.  I have my CSS.

Below is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
    theme="www/style.css" , 
    suppressDependencies("bootstrap"),
    
    tags$head(includeCSS("www/styles.css")),
    HTML('<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">
    <div id="wrapper-top">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                <li class="nav-item active mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link acces" href="/">Link</a>
                </li>
            </div>

        </ul>

    </div>
    </nav>'),
    tags$footer( HTML("<footer class='sticky-footer' role='footer'>
        <div class='container my-auto'>
            <div class='copyright text-center my-auto'>

                <span>©
                    2021
                    <a aria-label='' href=''>My footer</a>
                </span>

            </div>

        </div>

    </footer>")),
```

This gives me an output like this:

[image]

What I trying to achieve is to get the `navigation` below `body` tag currently it's all wrapped with this `container-fluid` class. And also I am trying to get the footer at the bottom of the page

Example:

[image]

Is there anyone that can help me with this? Thank you all

Comment: Short answer: don’t use a `fluidPage` wrapper. ;-) Checkout [`navbarPage`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/navbarPage.html).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thank you. How can I get custom HTML elements in navbarPage,  for example, a href="", or add custom css class?